# Erro ao alterar pela interface o tipo de dados de uma coluna

Tags: banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres, collation, dbeaver

Tento alterar o tipo de dados de `VARCHAR` para outro tipo de dados pela interface do sistema (não quero alterar via SQL) mas não consigo.

Tenho a seguinte tabela criada:

```
  CREATE TABLE `Usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sobrenome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_nascimento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `campo_int` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

E gostaria de mudar o campo_int de VARCHAR(100) para INT(11), mas não encontrei a opção de remover o charset e o collation referente ao campo. Não quero utilizar SQL para isso, quero modificar pela interface do DBeaver. Como devo proceder?

[image: Erro ocorrido]

[image: Interface do DBeaver]

Comment: O simples fato de mudar pra INT já deveria eliminar ambos. Se teve algum problema ao tentar a mudança, clique em [edit] e descreva na postagem, aí fica mais fácil uma solução.

Comment: Bom dia amigo alterei a imagem, realmente era para aceitar a mudança quando altero o tipo de dados para INT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após entrar em contato com o desenvolvedor do Dbeaver "serge-rider" o mesmo reportou que era um bug do sistema e já foi efetuada a correção. 
Realmente é um ótimo software.